# Espresso Test - how to to Write One Espresso Test which can be used for 2 Different Sourcesets(2 different APKS)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

i am looking for some inputs if anybody as any specific or relevant info about my scenario mentioned below :

In Our Android Project, we have one common Library folder and 2 separate(Different) App Folders. I have a requirement to write the Espresso Test for both the Apps. I have Written Espresso Test at the App Level(App->Src->AndroidTest->Java-PKG-LoginFlowTest.java) for both App Module, which is working fine. But now When i moved my Test Folder in Library Module (with same Level/Depth like in App), its not working. Throwing Below Error.

Error : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.xxx.xxxxxx.lib.test/xx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.lib.login.views.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'xx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.lib.dependency_injection.components.AppComponent xx.xxx.connected.lib.dependency_injection.DaggerInjector.getAppComponent()' on a null object reference

Here My intension is to write a Test common for both the Apps(2 different apps Generated using the same Source Sets with some different feature for both apps).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default Package for Android Tests is androidTest. If you use another package is not going to work unless you make some configuration changes on gradle.

If you have two 'app' in the root project, then they should have their own Espresso Tests under their 'androidTest' package.

It does not make sense to have two 'apps' and expect to write one espresso test for both of them. My understanding is that those 'apps' are not identical since they generate different apks.  If developers want to create multiple apks for the same project, then they can configure different flavors (debug, release, etc)  for a given project on gradle.